# .net core web api access to folder in container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, .net-core

In .net core web-api project needs to access to folder on container

How can I do it?

I need this to make the pictures return via web-api, but the pictures in the project itself are not worth it. Pictures are on the server(`/home/user/images`). And when I launch the docker, I add the command `-v /home/user/images:/mnt/images` to access from the container to the folder on the server. Issue - how to access from project to folder `/mnt/images` in docker container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do with your mount. .NET, running in your Docker Container will respect the Linux foward slash path and also me able to find your mount. And you can use System.IO methods to browse the mount directory and do anything you want with the files in that directory. Your path for System.IO classes that will help you get the image file and respond with it in an HTTP response, such as `Directory`, `File` is your mount path:

```
/mnt/images
```

So for example to see the files:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("/mnt/images");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles(); //Getting files

foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
  Console.Write(file.Name);
}
```